# ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (74216, 2) instead

Tags: nlp, logistic-regression, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer, train-test-split

I am trying to apply Logistic Regression Models with text.

I Vectorized my data by TFIDF:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_features=1500)
x = vectorizer.fit_transform(df['text_column'])

vectorizer_df = pd.DataFrame(x.toarray(), columns=vectorizer.get_feature_names())
df.drop('text_column', axis=1, inplace=True)  
result = pd.concat([df, vectorizer_df], axis=1)
```

I split my data:

```
x = result.drop('target', 1)
y = result['target']
```

and finally:

```
x_raw_train, x_raw_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.3,  random_state=0)
```

I build a classifier:

```
classifier = Pipeline([('clf', LogisticRegression(solver="liblinear"))])
classifier.fit(x_raw_train, y_train)
```

And I get this error:

```
ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (74216, 2) instead.
```

This is a strange thing because when I assign max_features=1000 it is working well, but when max_features=1500 I got an error.

Someone can help me please?

Comment: Can you please also add a sample of df?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the `text_column` column in `df` contains at least one occurrence *of the word *target**. This word becomes a column name when you convert the TF-IDF feature matrix to a dataframe with the parameter `columns=vectorizer.get_feature_names()`. Lastly, when you concatenate `df` with `vectorized_df`, you add both the `target` columns into the final dataframe.

Therefore, `result['target']` will return two columns instead of one as there are effectively two `target` columns in the `result` dataframe. This will naturally lead to a ValueError, because, as specified in the error description, you need a 1d target array to fit your estimator, whereas your target array has two columns.

The reason why you are encountering this for a high `max_features` threshold is simply because the word *target* isn't making the cut with the lower threshold allowing the process to run as it should.

Unless you have a reason to vectorize separately, the best solution for this is to combine all your steps in a pipeline. It's as simple as:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
                ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer(max_features=1500)),
                ('clf', LogisticRegression(solver="liblinear")),
                 ])
    
pipeline.fit(x_train.text_column, y_train.target)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I actually didn't pay attention to this issue.